# How to prove that this inequality holds

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital Banach algebra.

I wanted to prove the following inequality but didn't manage:

$$ \begin{align} 
\left | \|a\| - \inf_{d \in A: \|d\| = 1}\|bd\| \right | \le \inf_{\|d\|=1} \left | \|a\| - \|bd\|\right | 
\end{align}$$

Here $a \in A$. Now I am starting to doubt that it holds but I could also not find a counterexample. Could somebody either help me prove it or provide a counterexample? Thanks.

Comment: Why not also give the definition of the norm $\| \cdot \|$?

Comment: @daw I edited my question. It's now clearer.

Answer (score 0):

For every $d\in A$ such that $\|d\|=1$ one has 
$$\zeta(a)\leq\|bd\|+\|a-b\|.$$

So
$$\zeta(a)\leq\zeta(b)+\|a-b\|.$$

Using a symmetric reasoning we get
$$\zeta(b)\leq\zeta(a)+\|a-b\|,$$

and the inequality is proved.

Comment: Sorry, how does it prove inequality $(2)$ in my question? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: You changed the question completely. This answer proves the result you wanted to prove in the first place.

Comment: @daw The question was never about the result (I included the info merely for context): my question remains exactly the same as before: how to prove the inequality (I merely deleted the background info, see edit history to verify this). Feel free to remove your downvote on my question.